# Why is close(2) unfinished? Possible problem with multiple threads

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

RedHat Linux 7.9, kernel 3.10.0-1160.90.1.el7.x86_64, glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64. Yes, it's old- sorry.

In the Linux kernel, why does the close(2) kernel function sometimes doesn't finish in 1 call. I have seen a possible problem with multiple threads. If threads are open()ing, write()ing, and close()ing file descriptors, I have witnessed file descriptors in mid-close being reused in another thread from an open(). Then the close() completes, and when we try to write, we get a bad file descriptor.

Is this a feature, or a bug? I get that multiple threads share the file descriptor table so we may expect undefined behavior when juggling a file descriptor table as quickly as we are (see below), but I'm curious as to how the file descriptor is freed before the close() is complete.

Each thread's code is writing to file descriptors that it opens because we didn't know that when the clone() that is called when threads are open, actually shares the entire file descriptor table across all threads. Furthermore, we didn't forsee that a thread's open()/write()/close() set of operations would have a possible conflict due to a thread performing an open() in the middle of another thread's close(), wherein said close() had made the file descriptor available prior to complete cleanup and return.

Here is some output from strace which illustrates the behavior. Here we have two threads, 58506 and 58508. PID 58506 moves to close 12 at timestamp ending 532769. At 532791- 25 micros later- the close completes. But at timestamp 532775- 8 mics after 532769- PID 58508 opens a file. At 532803 (28 micros after it starts the open), the open completes and file descriptor 12 (which is now closed) is assigned to PID 58508. At 532949 the write is unsuccessful due to a bad file descriptor. This is 146 micros after 532803, when PID 58508 got the file descriptor.

This is on a local filesystem, on a Dell R640 server with a hardware RAID card backed by a pair of SSDs (for what it's worth).

```
58506 08:58:34.532769 close(12 <unfinished ...>

58508 08:58:34.532775 open("/path/to/dir1/file1", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0664 <unfinished ...>

58506 08:58:34.532791 <... close resumed>) = 0

58508 08:58:34.532803 <... open resumed>) = 12

58506 08:58:34.532808 close(12)         = 0

58508 08:58:34.532936 write(12, “datadatadatadata"..., 1572 <unfinished ...>

58506 08:58:34.532943 <... write resumed>) = 258

58508 08:58:34.532949 <... write resumed>) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

58506 08:58:34.532963 stat("/path/to/dir2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...})
 = 0
58506 08:58:34.532995 open("/path/to/dir2/file2", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0664) = 12


58508 08:58:34.533286 close(12)         = 0
58508 08:58:34.533311 close(12)         = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

58508 08:58:34.533595 write(1, "[2023-10-04 08:58:34.533588 E] P"..., 216) = 216

58506 08:58:34.533634 write(12, "moredatadatadatadata"..., 6139) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
58506 08:58:34.533660 close(12)         = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

58508 08:58:34.533681 nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000},  <unfinished ...>

58506 08:58:34.533688 close(12)         = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
58506 08:58:34.533709 stat("/path/to/dir2/file2", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
58506 08:58:34.533760 write(1, "[2023-10-04 08:58:34.533754 E] P"..., 233) = 233
58506 08:58:34.533786 nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000},  <unfinished ...>
```

At timestamp 533709 the developer checks the file to see if it's 0-length. The file has indeed been created but the write had failed, so there is no data in it. Thus the code enters a loop and tries to rewrite the file.

POSIX requires that pthread() copy open file descriptors to child threads (https://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads), but it says nothing about file descriptors that are opened by children.

I'm a little nervous that close() is a cancellation point "this meaning it is safe from the point of view of the OS to cancel the thread while this function is executed" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374707/what-exactly-is-a-cancellation-point, see accepted answer). But if the close()ing thread is cancelled, then another thread could have an invalid file descriptor...? Is the OS guaranteed to have a proper file descriptor table at that time? I suppose so, but this free of the file descriptor before close() is done makes me nervous.

Comment: Why is your code trying to write to file descriptor 12 at all if another thread can close it at any time?

Comment: @AndrewHenle updated the question. We are simply open()/write()/close(). The fact that  it's possible that another thread could close our file descriptor is the point of the question. We expect that at a successful open(), we are given a valid file descriptor.

Comment: I see double `close`s from the same thread, and a `write` after a `close` in the same thread with no intervening `open` — are you sure the sequences *per thread* are OK? There’s some discussion of all this in [`man 2 close`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html).

Comment: @MikeS *POSIX requires that pthread() copy open file descriptors to child threads* Huh?!? From your own link (bolding mine):  "POSIX.1 also requires that threads **share** a range of other attributes ... open file descriptors".  If thread A closes file descriptor 12, file descriptor 12 is closed for **every** single thread in the process.

Comment: @AndrewHenle agreed. It IS closed for every single thread. So it appeared to us to be closed for thread 58508 above by 58506, even after 58508 performs an open() and gets fd 12, which 58506 had. Now after reading Stephen Kitt's comment, I think our problem is simply an additional close(). I had read the (<... close resumed>) line as meaning that the close didn't finish fully until timestamp 532808, but I actually think that is a second close. And there's our problem.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt That's interesting. See my above comment. But at 532943 we have a write resumed, and a return code of 258, on a write that takes place after a close at 532808...?

Comment: We don’t see where the resumed write started, so it’s hard to draw conclusions from its behaviour after it resumes. As described in `man 2 close`, blocking operations keep a reference to the underlying file description, and can complete after the descriptor is closed.

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks, yeah- well, as it turns out, the write is to stdout... :eggonface: